# Android: WallpaperService working with xml layout

Tags: android, xml, live-wallpaper

How can I create an android layout for wallpaperService? Is it possible? For now I just found [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLiveWallpaper/article.html) tutorial, that is working with canvas.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

In a Wallpaper service you don't get acccess to the whole ui toolkit.
You can't use views to lay things out. 
That is one fo the reasons Daydreams where introduced, where all that is possible.